# What is the best role for a low fitness player in futsal?

Tags: strategy, futsal

I used to play futsal; however, I got a little over-weight and lost my fitness recently. I love the game and in the same time do not want to be a weakness point for my team.

What is the position (or role) that needs the least effort in a futsal game?

Comment: Try to start out as a keeper and when players get tired, swap yourself into outfield role. Increase your time in an outfield role with every game and soon you'll regain your stamina to be able to play at a respectable level within a month or so.

Comment: I have no idea why this question is closed. Sure, the answer is going to be "what is the role less likely to harm my team", rather than "what is the best role", but this is easily answerable. It's goalkeeper. They are not required to run as much, either on or off the ball. In fact - in futsal, once they have released the ball, they usually cannot even get it back again. The majority of their play consists of quick sprints to make last-ditch challenges, and saves, which do not drain stamina as much as the continuous movement required in other roles.

Comment: In the title, you referred to the sport as futsal, then elsewhere - five-a-side football. Futsal is a clearly-defined sport with clearly-defined rules, while five-a-side football is not. In fact, I'm confused as to why we do not have a futsal tag.

Comment: @studro [futsal tag created](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/futsal).

Answer (score 4):

Futsal is a very "quick" sport. Usually players has to run a lot (like in basketball). That's why this kind of sports has a big rotation of players on the field.

If you are playing friendly, the last defender could be a nice position, only covering your own half and helping attacking from the center of the field.

If you need a rest, being a goalkeeper is the easiest position to rest, since you barely leave the penalty area.

That's always depends on the type of game you are playing. If you are playing in a league, you will have to make sure your teammates doesn't fill all the positions you can handle. Or make sure that the team has replacement players. If you have a good goalkeeper (this position needs a lot of reflex, the ball in this game goes very fast), then stick to be the last defender. And start training to regain your fitness.